# Oracle - wrong result using sysdate

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime, where-clause

I have the following query. This query does not return any result:

```
select snap_id from perfstat.stats$snapshot where snap_time = sysdate;

no rows selected
```

but if I format the snap_time and sysdate I receive the result:

```
select snap_id 
from perfstat.stats$snapshot 
where to_char(snap_time,'dd/mm/yyyy') = to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy');

SNAP_ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

Is there something wrong with my query? Why do I need format the date in this context?

obs: the column snap_time is date type.

Comment: CONVERT is to be used for another purposes (when it is about different character sets), not this (i.e. date format), @paulsm4.

Comment: The reason for the behaviour you're seeing is that a *DATE* also has a time part, and therefore, a naive check for equality will only succeed if both dates match to the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `where` clauses of the queries are not identical.

The first query tries to match `snap_date` against the current date and time. This is not likely to succeed, unless a snap was created at the very same second when the query is executed.

The second query compares the date part `snap_date` against the current day (the time part is not taken into account).

This:

```
where to_char(snap_time,'dd/mm/yyyy') = to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Actually means:

```
where trunc(snap_time) = trunc(sysdate)
```

Which can, (and should) be optimized as the clearer and more efficient:

```
where snap_time  >= trunc(sysdate)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will never forget about it!